# How do I calculate the x & y dimensions of pin 1 for a QFN package?

Tags: pcb, altium, design, qfn

I'm trying to make changes in pad location. How do I calculate the x & y location of pin 1? Is there any mathematical calculation, how do I do those calculations?

I'm sharing an  image of a QFN package.
Can you tell me the exact dimensions of pin1?

[image]

Comment: Hi! not quite sure what you ask: this is a dimensional drawing, *nothing* has an absolute location, everything is just relative. So, you can just *set* an arbitrary location for pin 1. For example, putting the center of pin 1 to (0,0) is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: or is "location" a typo in your first sentence? But then I understand the question even less: the dimension of that pad is given in the drawing as L×b, and these are given in the table.

Comment: if you need the reference for pick and place - the usual is the centre of the package and a rotation. For placing pads where the placement point is the centre of the pad, derive a rectangle that describes the middle of the pads as per the mech drawing and place pads on that rectangle.

Comment: Are you manually creating a footprint? Tyr to enter the package data into the IPC footprint wizzard and it will create the footpinrt for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you  creating a footprint?
I recoment to enter the package data into the IPC footprint wizzard and it will create an reasonable footprint for you which includes all tolerance topics.

Or:
Assumeing you have the center of the thermal pad at position X=0/y=0
The center of the Pin #1 pad is at L/2 from the most left edge. (Create the footprint from Top View)
The space between the central thermal pad to the surrounding pin is: Space = (D-D2-2*L)/2

Place the Center of pad 1 at
X Koordinate: X = D2/2 + Space + L/2
Y Koordinate: Y = E2/2 - b/2